# Nuxt update session cookie with each request

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, session-cookies, fastify

I am building a Nuxt app that uses fastify for the backend API. I am using httpOnly session-cookies for authentication. So far everything works fine but the issue i have is that Nuxt just has a hardcoded cookie timeout of 30 minutes. I have updated this to 24hrs but what i really want to do is have Nuxt refresh the timeout after each request.

I see in my database that the fastify session cookie get updated after each request and the session expiration gets updated after ANY user API request. So, this looks like the backend is functioning correctly but the frontend need to update the `auth._token_expiration.local` value.

You can see in the config that i manually set the maxAge to 24hrs, cant i have the frontend update the `auth._token_expiration.local` value automatically when making successful API requests? my token is stored as `sessionId`

nuxt.config.js

```
  auth: {
    redirect: false,
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          required: false,
          type: false,
          maxAge: 86400 // seconds - 1 day
        },
        user: { property: false },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/user/login',
            method: 'post',
            withCredentials: true
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/user/logout',
            method: 'post',
            withCredentials: true
          },
          user: {
            url: '/user/profile',
            method: 'get',
            withCredentials: true
          }
        }
      },
      localStorage: false,
      cookie: true
    }
  },
```

Comment: You will need to look for the call and see if it get an `unauthorized` error, then you could call the auth's manual refresh method.

Comment: @kissu Im looking for any call to fail with 401? What is Nuxt going to use to get a new cookie? Im confused.

Comment: `refreshTokens()` as shown in the documentation: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#refreshtokens

Comment: @kissu when I manually call that method it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: It should reach to your endpoints and ask for a new token thanks to the `refresh_token`. Double check your client side cookies.

Comment: @kissu, what endpoint would it call? I have no endpoint that does any type of 'refreshing' of the token. devtools shows no requests to anything

Answer (score 0):

So i discovered that the `sessionId` Expires data DOES get updated after each api request, so that is good. To make this function i also had to set the nuxt.config token maxAge to 0. This solved my issues.